# Confusion with Python Comparison Expressions and 'in' Operator

Tags: python

Consider the following code snippets:

```
("x" in "x") != True
```

The output is: `False`, which is expected

```
"x" in "x" != True
```

The output is: `True`, which is different from expected, so one might think the operators are read from right to left.

However:

```
"x" in ("x" != True)
```

Results in a `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable.`

I initially expected the outputs of the first two snippets to be the same regardless of the order, but the results are different.
Furthermore, the third snippet raises a `TypeError`, where I suspected the Python behavior to work this way.

Could someone please explain the logic behind these outcomes?

Answer (score 2):

No, the operators are not read from right to left.

In Python, unlike (most) other languages,

```
"x" in "x" != True
```

is equivalent to

```
("x" in "x") and ("x" != True)
```

Both statements are indeed true.

It's a bit unintuitive in your case, but it's made such that you can do something like:

```
0 < x < 20
```

to check the value is within the (0, 20) range, instead of cumbersome:

```
x > 0 and x < 20
```

Comment: that explains a lot. Tahnks!